# In emacs, how to change the default so ctrl-c copies and ctrl-v pastes?

Tags: emacs

It seems much better to have its default be the same as the other things. So, is there a way to do it? Does it conflict with any commands?

Comment: on a side note.. with C-c there are so many bindings in many modes which are very useful.. you probably don't want to miss/rebind them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emacs includes a mode for this called CUA-Mode. It implements a keymap and behavior a little closer to what you're probably used to, including cut and paste.  You can enable it with <kbd>M-x cua-mode</kbd>.

There's some additional information in the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html#CUA-Bindings) and on [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can redefine Emacs keyboard shortcuts to be compatible with Windows applications. Check for example [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsCustomize) page.

From my experience it's not a good idea. If you want to use Emacs you will use it extensively. You will do as many tasks in Emacs as you can.

And you need to use many of Emacs shortcuts which are inter-connected. So by re-defining some of them you make it difficult to remember other.

Comment: Ditto, emacs's closest relative to copy/paste, known as kill/yank, is a very different thing so leaving it bound to a different key helps you not to hamstring yourself by thinking of it in the same way.  Be sure you do `C-h t`, it will get you up to speed.